# RuntimeException with React Native Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, react-native

Recently we've integrated react native into our app with just simple text view. We're getting this crash on all kind of devices.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.create(null)') (index.android.bundle:2)
       at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java)
       at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:33)
       at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:177)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:918)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:911)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$1.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:74)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

We show simple text with React Native

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>React Native is running</Text>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('8fit', () => HelloWorld);
```

We use React Native `0.35.0-rc.0` but we've been getting same crash also with stable release `0.33.1`.

You can find full crash report here.
https://gist.github.com/sealskej/4c9aa89e32d96103f588459b5b0c70d1

Any help leading to fixing issue would be much appreciated!